# Reduce the size of Ubuntu server

Tags: server, ldap

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 VM and would like to reduce the size on the HDD.

I have only to run :

- a ldap server
- a keycloak server
- a freeradius server

I have already remove snapd.

Is there a method to process?

For example to use `keycloak` I have to install `openjdk` but may be only a part of the installed package with `openjdk` are needed?

Or maybe remove some documentation coming with a package?

Comment: I doubt you will get more than a few mb out of it.  The better option would be to increase the size of the vm,

Comment: The usual method for reducing the size of a VM is to use an Ubuntu Server [cloud image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com) (0.5G) instead of a bare-metal Ubuntu Server Live image (1.4GB). Cloud images include a [minimal](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/) .img option (0.3G) for expert use. Be aware that Ubuntu developers aim for a robust user experience, not a minimal experience. Other distros fill that niche.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command to see which packages can potentially be removed from a standard system:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Package;-40}${Status;-26}${Priority}\n' | sort -b -k5,5 -k1,1 | grep -v 'required\|important\|standard'| grep 'installed' | less
```

This will list all installed packages with a [priority](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-priorities) of "optional" or "extra".

However, be advised that you won't really gain that much disk space by removing individual packages this way. Also, note that some important packages are still listed as "optional" (kernels, for instance).

But you can use this list as a basis to do some trial and error about which packages can be removed (should be fairly easy on a VM).

I wouldn't recommend manually tinkering with the contents that come with individual packages (e.g. documentation etc.), unless you really know what you're doing.